# mips : 1 t~ 100 odd sum (blank fill)

Tags: mips

Find the sum of 1 to 100 odd pieces of mips.
Fill in the "#Fill in" section.
I'm hard. Help me.

.data
 msg: .asciiz "Sum of odd number: "
 number: .word 100

.text
 .globl main

mian:
   lw $s0,number
 #Fill in.

loop:
 #Fill in.

li $v0,4
 la $a0, msg
 syscall

li $v0,1
 addi $a0,$t2,0
 syscall

li $v0,10
 syscall

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
.data 

 msg: .asciiz "Sum of odd number: " 
 #number: .word 100
 .text 
 .globl main

main: 

  #lw $t0,number #Fill in.
  xor   $t0,$t0,$t0
  addiu $t0,$t0,100

 loop: #Fill in.
   rem $t1,$t0,2
   beq $t1,1,is_odd
   j dec_number

is_odd:
 addu  $t2,$t2,$t0
dec_number:
  subiu $t0,$t0,1
  beq $t0,0,end_loop
j loop

end_loop:
li $v0,4 
la $a0, msg 

syscall

li $v0,1 
addi $a0,$t2,0 
syscall

li $v0,10 
syscall
```